# R sorting/ordering stacked variables

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

Very similar: [How to sort dataframe in R with specified column order preservation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166285/how-to-sort-dataframe-in-r-with-specified-column-order-preservation)

An example of my data:

```
> dat
   type    attr   y1
1  x1         A 0.25
2  x1         B 0.19
3  x1         C 0.06
4  x1         D 0.13
5  x2         A 0.25
6  x2         B 0.00
7  x2         C 0.19
8  x2         D 0.00
```

I'm creating a few different plots and want to do the following:

- sort by y1, but only according to x1's y1 values
- have x2 order itself by whatever order attr is in after doing the previous step

In other words, for this example, I want the result:

```
> datsorted
   type    attr   y1
1  x1         C 0.06
2  x1         D 0.13 
3  x1         B 0.19 
4  x1         A 0.25
5  x2         C 0.19
6  x2         D 0.00
7  x2         B 0.00
8  x2         A 0.25
```

The only way I currently knew to do this was insanely tedious. I created two subset dataframes based on the value of `type` (one for x1, one for x2). Then I created a new dataframe like this:

```
> beside
   t1  t2   attr   x1y1  x2y1
1  x1  x2   A      0.25  0.25
2  x1  x2   B      0.19  0.00
3  x1  x2   C      0.06  0.19
4  x1  x2   D      0.13  0.00
```

That way I can sort by x1y1 and keep everything together... but then I have to re-split it up in long form to plot. There has to be a better way. Sorry if I've missed another answer; I'm newer to R and am not even sure what to search for!

---

Per the suggestion below, here's the raw data:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("x1", "x2"), class = "factor"), attr = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    y1 = c(0.25, 0.19, 0.06, 0.13, 0.25, 0, 0.19, 0)), .Names = c("type", 
"attr", "y1"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what you want to do, you can use:

```
ord <- order(dat[dat$type=="x1",]$y1)
dat.sorted <- rbind(dat[ord,], dat[ord + 4,])
```

Essentially what this is doing is:

1. selecting the data where type=x1

   `dat[dat$type=="x1",]`
2. getting the order of y1 in those and putting it in `ord`

   `order(dat[dat$type=="x1",]$y1)`
3. order your (partial) data

   `dat[ord,]`
4. ordering the rest of the data as the first part
   **NOTE: this only works if the first 4 elements are x1 and the 2nd 4 are x2**

   `dat[ord+4,]`
5. merging it with the ordered data

   `dat.sorted <- rbind(dat[ord,], dat[ord+4,])`

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I simplified things above and added `dput(dat)` as requested. I was going to ask, but now know the answer after trying this, "What sorts the second part of the data that is not x1?" I didn't mistype in my second table showing how I want things sorted. I'd like to sort by x1's y1 variables, which will give me an order for the `attr` vector; then I'd like to sort x2 by that `attr` sort order. I think I can use your code to do that, though. Give me a sec.

Comment: Nope. Not getting it. I need that first half to tell me what order it ends up putting `attrs` into (C,D,B,A); then I need that second half to order itself like that. Right now, your function gives me x1 with `attrs` order C,D,B,A, but x2 is stacked below it in the original A,B,C,D ordering. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in three steps:

1. `xtabs` transforms your data.frame into a 2D array (table): `attr`-by-`type`
2. sort the array along the `attr` dimension
3. return to a data.frame using `as.data.frame.table`

---

```
a <- xtabs(y1 ~ attr + type, dat)
a
#     type
# attr   x1   x2
#    A 0.25 0.25
#    B 0.19 0.00
#    C 0.06 0.19
#    D 0.13 0.00

b <- a[order(a[, "x1"]), ]
b
#     type
# attr   x1   x2
#    C 0.06 0.19
#    D 0.13 0.00
#    B 0.19 0.00
#    A 0.25 0.25

as.data.frame.table(b, responseName = "y")
#   attr type    y
# 1    C   x1 0.06
# 2    D   x1 0.13
# 3    B   x1 0.19
# 4    A   x1 0.25
# 5    C   x2 0.19
# 6    D   x2 0.00
# 7    B   x2 0.00
# 8    A   x2 0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

From the subset where `type` is `x1`:

```
dat.x1 <- subset(dat, type == "x1")
```

find the attributes corresponding to increasing values of `y1`:

```
ord.attr <- dat.x1$attr[order(dat.x1$y1)]
ord.attr
# [1] C D B A
# Levels: A B C D
```

then use ply'r `arrange` function to sort your data.frame:

```
require(plyr)
arrange(dat, type, match(attr, ord.attr))
#   type attr   y1
# 1   x1    C 0.06
# 2   x1    D 0.13
# 3   x1    B 0.19
# 4   x1    A 0.25
# 5   x2    C 0.19
# 6   x2    D 0.00
# 7   x2    B 0.00
# 8   x2    A 0.25
```